# Search results scraping using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, export-to-csv

I scraped Google search results using Python, exactly, getting the number of search results for each keyword and saving them in a CSV file. But after almost 100 keyword searches, it showed [Not Found] instead of the number.

[image].

I think I get blocked by Google or something, I heard about IP blocking and API limits and I don't know if these are the problem.

This is the code that I used:

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Read the keywords from a file
with open("keywords.txt", "r") as file:
    keywords = file.read().splitlines()

# Define the User-Agent header
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3"}

# Create a new CSV file and write the headers
with open("results.csv", "w", newline="") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(["Keyword", "Total Results"])

    # Perform the search for each keyword and write the total number of results to the CSV file
    for keyword in keywords:
        response = requests.get(f"https://www.google.com/search?q={keyword}", headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
        result_stats = soup.find("div", {"id": "result-stats"})
        if result_stats:
            total_results = result_stats.get_text().split()[1].replace(",", "")
            writer.writerow([keyword, total_results])
            print(f"Keyword: {keyword}, Total Results: {total_results}")
        else:
            writer.writerow([keyword, "Not found"])
            print(f"Keyword: {keyword}, Total Results: Not found")
```

Please if the code is the issue fix it, if not let me know what to do

I tried Python bueatyfulsoup, bs4, requests

Comment: Could you clarify your question? Google blocks IP addresses because they don't want people scraping their search results. It's also against their Terms of Service: https://policies.google.com/terms?hl=en-US#toc-what-we-expect

Comment: Thanks for your comment, If my IP addresses really get blocked by Google how can I solve this, and how to avoid it the next time?

Answer (score -1):

It is possible that you are encountering Google's anti-scraping measures, such as IP blocking and API limits, as you have suspected. When you send too many requests to Google in a short period of time, Google may start blocking your IP address or CAPTCHA-ing your requests to prevent further scraping.

To avoid these issues, you can try the following:

1)Slow down your requests: You can add a delay between each request to avoid sending too many requests in a short period of time. You can use the time.sleep() function to add a delay.

2)Use proxies: You can use proxies to make requests from different IP addresses and avoid getting blocked by Google. There are many proxy services available that you can use.

3)Use a Google API: Instead of scraping Google search results, you can use the Google Custom Search API or Google Search Console API to retrieve search results. These APIs are designed for this purpose and are less likely to trigger anti-scraping measures.

Comment: Yes, I get CAPTCHA even in manual searching. after getting blocked will my IP be working again? and I think proxy services will be good for me, but how to use them?

Comment: If you have been temporarily blocked by Google, your IP address should become unblocked after a period of time (usually several hours). However, if you continue to make too many requests in a short period of time, Google may block your IP address again. To avoid being blocked, it's best to limit the number of requests you make per hour and per day.

To use a proxy server, you can modify your code to make the requests through the proxy server instead of directly to Google. Here's an example using the requests library